# Using separate and mutate functions

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and trying to mutate the following character variable "Tax.Rate..." into four different columns (i.e., CGST, SGST, UTGST, and IGST) with tax rates applicable to that head under that column. Example of dataset shown below:

> df
> # A tibble: 3 x 1
> Tax.Rate....
>
> 1 "CGST 2.5% + SGST 2.5%"
> 2 "CGST 6% + UTGST 6%"
> 3 "IGST 12% "

I have tried using 'separate' and 'mutate' functions with little success

Any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this can be done concisely in base R as well, but here's a tidyverse approach where I first split the data into a new row at each plus, then trim the extra spaces, then split into two columns.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Tax.Rate = c("CGST 2.5% + SGST 2.5%", "CGST 6% + UTGST 6%", "IGST 12% "))

df %>%
  mutate(orig_row = row_number()) %>% # optional, for later tracking
  separate_rows(Tax.Rate, sep = "\\+") %>%
  mutate(Tax.Rate = str_trim(Tax.Rate)) %>%
  separate(Tax.Rate, c("group", "rate"), extra = "merge", remove = FALSE)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
  Tax.Rate  group rate  orig_row
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>    <int>
1 CGST 2.5% CGST  2.5%         1
2 SGST 2.5% SGST  2.5%         1
3 CGST 6%   CGST  6%           2
4 UTGST 6%  UTGST 6%           2
5 IGST 12%  IGST  12%          3
```

This will produce a "long" shaped table, but if you want it "wide" with separate columns for each group (jurisdiction?) then you could add the following:

```
[from the end of the "separate()" line] %>%
select(-Tax.Rate) %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = rate)
```

for this result

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  orig_row CGST  SGST  UTGST IGST 
     <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1        1 2.5%  2.5%  NA    NA   
2        2 6%    NA    6%    NA   
3        3 NA    NA    NA    12%
```

Comment: to @Jon Spring: I am not sure, may it is clear but i think grouping and adding an id is also an idea to get this `df %>%
  mutate(orig_row = row_number()) %>% # optional, for later tracking
  separate_rows(Tax.Rate, sep = "\\+") %>%
  mutate(Tax.Rate = str_trim(Tax.Rate)) %>%
  separate(Tax.Rate, c("group", "rate"), extra = "merge", remove = FALSE) %>% 
  select(-Tax.Rate, -orig_row) %>%
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = group, values_from = rate)`

Answer (score 1):

We could:

1. Use `separate_rows` separating by `+` using `\\+` to escape the special character
2. then `str_trim` to remove starting space etc...
3. `separate` this column by `" "`
   4.`group_by` and add `id` to avoid nested output
4. `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  separate_rows(Tax.Rate, sep = "\\+") %>% 
  mutate(Tax.Rate = str_trim(Tax.Rate)) %>% 
  separate(Tax.Rate, c("name", "value"), sep = " ") %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = name, 
    values_from = value
  ) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
  CGST  SGST  UTGST IGST 
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2.5%  2.5%  6%    12%  
2 6%    NA    NA    NA
```

data:

```
structure(list(Tax.Rate = c("CGST 2.5% + SGST 2.5%", "CGST 6% + UTGST 6%", 
"IGST 12%")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```